# Rails 4 partial rendering object is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've ben perusing http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render and have tried all the different partial options, but to no avail.

I have a `trouble_tickets` action with my `Client` controller, like so (simplified):

```
def trouble_tickets
  @query = Client.get_job_count
  respond_to do |format|
      format.html
  end
end
```

`get_job_count` is defined in my `Client` model:

```
def self.get_job_count
  find_by_sql("my sql query here that returns some data");  
end
```

In `app/views/pages` I have a `dashboard.html.erb` file which does the following:

`<%= render partial: "clients/trouble_tickets", object: @query %>`

Then in `_trouble_tickets.html.erb` (which is within `app/views/clients`) I have:

```
<% @query.each do |item| %>
   <tr>
     <td><%= item.attributes['Job Code'] %></td>
     <td><%= item.attributes['Percentage'].round(2) %>%</td>    
   </tr>
<% end %>
```

When loading `/dashboard`, I receive an error message of:

`undefined method`each' for nil:NilClass`

Why is this happening? Am I not using the `object` attribute in the partial rendering correctly?

Note: I have tried this `@query` iteration in my normal view of `trouble_tickets.html.erb` and can see the data just fine.

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial:

`<%= render partial: "clients/trouble_tickets", locals: {query_objects: @query} %>`

Loop:

```
<% query_objects.each do |item| %>
   <tr>
     <td><%= item.attributes['Job Code'] %></td>
     <td><%= item.attributes['Percentage'].round(2) %>%</td>    
   </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Same exact error message though. Why does it think it is `nil` ?

Comment: r u sure your `@query = Client.get_job_count` returns data ? also, i think the problem in dashboard. Goto your controller where dashboard method located and add this one there `@query = Client.get_job_count` thats should be fine.

Comment: Yes, most definitely. In my non-partial trouble tickets view, this data appears correctly. See here: https://gist.github.com/ornerymoose/4351e259e71b3a4a955c87aa108e4278

Comment: ok, u want to use that partial, through dashboard. in your case you are doing it not right way. your instance supposed to be in dashboard not in partial. you have to call partial and add it there instance, such as like with `locals:`.

Comment: Yep you're right about the dashboard (which is in the `pages` controller). Why is that though? Shouldnt referencing the clients view folder in the partial call take care of that?

Comment: and in other case, some how, if u want to use that partial again in different page example in `users` page. you are doing the same thing. calling partial in users and adding instances there with `locals:` its like DRY(dnt repeat yrself). u can call it anywhere  in the app any time just passing right object u want to print there.

Comment: Interesting. I really appreciate all of your responses.